# The meaning of "box" in "box score"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "box" in "[box score](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/box_score#English)" mean featured printed matter enclosed by hairlines, a border, or white space and placed within or between text columns.? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scores are arranged in a *table*, and the word 'box' is often used to mean a drawn or printed square around text. If you are familiar with word processors or other publishing software, you may know that you can create *text boxes*.

Webster's dictionary explains the etymology beneath its definition of 'box score':

> from its arrangement in a newspaper box

Newspaper text and articles may be separated in different ways. Sometimes there is a visible box around text, or a line between columns; other publications may just leave a gap. Similarly, text boxes drawn in software such as a word processor may have visible borders or not - it still confines the text to a box. The visibility of a border doesn't matter, there is still a box.

Comment: Thank you so very much for you detailed explanations